# Databricks Spark: java.lang.OutOfMemoryError: GC overhead limit exceeded i

Tags: apache-spark, databricks, azure-databricks

I am executing a Spark job in Databricks cluster. I am triggering the job via a Azure Data Factory pipeline and it execute at 15 minute interval so after the `successful execution of three or four times` it is getting failed and throwing with the exception `"java.lang.OutOfMemoryError: GC overhead limit exceeded"`. 
Though there are many answer with for the above said question but in most of the cases their jobs are not running but in my cases it is getting failed after successful execution of some previous jobs.
My data size is less than 20 MB only.

My cluster configuration is:
[image: Databricks cluster Configuration]

So the my question is what changes I should make in the server configuration. If the issue is coming from my code then why it is getting succeeded most of the time. Please advise and suggest me the solution.

Comment: whoever is down voting should mention the reason.

Comment: upvoted but not the downvoter

Answer (score 0):

This is most probably related to executor memory being bit low .Not sure what is current setting and if its default what is the default value in this particular databrics distribution. Even though it passes  but there would lot of GCs happening because of low memory hence it would keep failing once in a while . Under spark configuration please provide spark.executor.memory and also some other params related to num of executors and cores per executor . In spark-submit the config would be provided as spark-submit --conf spark.executor.memory=1g

Comment: Hey @Shridhar I am looking for the exact solution rather than the generic answer.

Comment: Solution is to have  spark.executor.memory=1g but sorry i am not sure how to do that from the way you are starting the app . Probably you can add in spark config section provided under advanced options

Answer (score 0):

You may try increasing memory of driver node.

Comment: would need more explanation on how to do it.

Comment: Increase the computing power of driver node in cluster configuration page. E.g. the snapshot above says 8 cores with 16GB memory - try choosing different configuration with higher memory and see

Answer (score 0):

Sometimes the Garbage Collector is not releasing all the loaded objects in the driver's memory.

What you can try is to force the GC to do that. You can do that by executing the following:

```
spark.catalog.clearCache()
for (id, rdd) in spark.sparkContext._jsc.getPersistentRDDs().items():
    rdd.unpersist()
    print("Unpersisted {} rdd".format(id))
```